# Moving moon explanation

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, relative-motion

I saw the moon moving in a fast pace several times with the naked eye, even during day time when its cloudy. How is that possible?

I asked my teacher about it and he said its just an illusion, but this explanation isn't satisfactory.

Comment: Could you explain it further please.

Comment: The Moon's motion is too slow to see, but it can look like it's moving fast if you see it through thin fast-moving cloud.

Comment: Relative motion! Ignore the clouds and compare the moon's position to a tree or building.  Most illusions are due to distracting reference frames. Your teacher is corrent.

Comment: @PM2Ring You *can* see the moon move, exactly if it is passing right over a tree, a pointed roof, or similar that gives you a precise mark to measure against. My son and I just did it a week or so ago. it is slow, but you can see it.

Comment: @Thriveth That's true, but the motion is barely perceptible, like watching a shadow in sunlight, or the minute hand of an analogue clock. The OP is talking about a more rapid sense of motion. FWIW, from the balcony in my previous house I could sometimes see the full Moon rise behind an island. It was wonderful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the relative velocity combined with the angular and linear separations that the moon appears to move fast. It is actually the clouds that make you feel so.